How can I further aggregate the results of my graph traversal?
Using the example graph that can be created from the code below, how can I get counts of unique vehicles parked in different locations during a time interval? I need the solution to include information from other nodes, as is included in my query attempts.
Code for creating the graph (using Tinkerpop 3.7.2 from here):
// A graph of vehicles parked in parking slots
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal();

// three parking locations, each with 3 slots
for (parking in ['Mayfair', 'Euston', 'GareDuNord']) {
    g.addV('parking').property('name', parking).iterate();
    for (slot = 1; slot < 4; slot++) {
        var slotName = String.format('%s %s', parking, slot);
        g.addV('slot').property('name', slotName).
        addE('hasSlot').from(__.V().has('parking', 'name', parking)).iterate();
    }
}

// the parking locations are in two different cities
g.addV('city').property('name', 'London').addE('hasParking').to(__.V().has('parking', 'name', 'Mayfair'));
g.V().has('city', 'name', 'London').addE('hasParking').to(__.V().has('parking', 'name', 'Euston'));
g.addV('city').property('name', 'Paris').addE('hasParking').to(__.V().has('parking', 'name', 'GareDuNord'));

// see all the parking places and slots:
// g.V().hasLabel('parking').bothE().elementMap()

// we have 3 vehicles that can park, and three points in time
locationMaps = [
    'v1': ['Mayfair 1', 'Euston 2', 'GareDuNord 3'],
    'v2': ['Mayfair 2', 'Mayfair 3', 'Mayfair 1'],
    'v3': ['Mayfair 3', null, 'Euston 1']
]
for (lMap in locationMaps) {
    vehicleName = lMap.key;
    g.addV('vehicle').property('name', vehicleName).iterate();
    locations = lMap.value;
    t = 1;
    for (locationName in locations) {
        if (locationName != null) {
            g.V().has('vehicle', 'name', vehicleName).
                addE('parkedAt').to(__.V().has('slot', 'name', locationName)).
                property('time', t).iterate();
        }
        t += 1;
    }
}

// all the parking events
// g.E().hasLabel('parkedAt').elementMap()

This is my best effort so far:
// how to get counts of distinct vehicles parked in all parking locations in a city during an interval?
g.V().hasLabel('city').
    out('hasParking').
    out('hasSlot').
    inE('parkedAt').has('time', P.lte(2)).has('time', P.gte(1)).
    project('city', 'parking', 'vehicle').
    by(inV().in('hasSlot').in('hasParking').values('name')).
    by(inV().in('hasSlot').values('name')).
    by(outV().values('name')).
    dedup()

// this is output:
// ==>[city:London,parking:Mayfair,vehicle:v1]
// ==>[city:London,parking:Mayfair,vehicle:v2]
// ==>[city:London,parking:Mayfair,vehicle:v3]
// ==>[city:London,parking:Euston,vehicle:v1]

// but I want this:
// ==>[city:London,parking:Mayfair,count:3]
// ==>[city:London,parking:Euston,count:1]

This query gets a list of distinct combinations, but how to get the counts per city and parking?
I also tried gathering the required data using path(), like this:
g.V().hasLabel('city').
    out('hasParking').
    out('hasSlot').
    inE('parkedAt').has('time', P.lte(2)).has('time', P.gte(1)).
    outV().
    path().
    by('name').         // city
    by('name').         // parking
    by(constant('')).   // slot - not wanted
    by(constant('')).   // vehicle-parkedAt->slot edge - not wanted
    by('name').         // vehicle
    dedup()

This gives a very similar result (without the mapping keys, which I'd prefer to keep). But I still don't know how to count the unique vehicles without losing either the city or the parking details. Also in the real use-case, sometimes we need more than piece of information from a single path step (how do you do this?).
The query will be run on a JanusGraph server using gremlin-python. Some things do not work as might be expected in this setup, especially labels cannot be indexed, so starting with g.V().hasLabel('vehicle') would be a bad idea. I'm pretty sure that lambdas are unavailable as well. We have other difficulties but cannot say whether they are real differences or just our lack of understanding.

Right, this is so straightforward it is embarrassing. The key was to group by the two map keys that I wanted to keep, and there's a handy groupCount() to make it even easier. Like this:
g.V().hasLabel('city').
    out('hasParking').
    out('hasSlot').
    inE('parkedAt').has('time', P.lte(2)).has('time', P.gte(1)).
    project('city', 'parking', 'vehicle').
    by(inV().in('hasSlot').in('hasParking').values('name')).
    by(inV().in('hasSlot').values('name')).
    by(outV().values('name')).
    dedup().
    groupCount().
    by(select('city', 'parking')).
    unfold()


It's worth noting I got some inspiration from this blog post. Thanks Kristine Marhilevica!
